# Why is Swagger/Swashbuckle mangling my routes?

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a controller with the following methods on it:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
[System.Web.Mvc.Route("api/v1.0/foo/{id}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(MyObject))]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)

[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
[System.Web.Mvc.Route("api/v1.0/foo/{id}/address")]
[ResponseType(typeof(MyObject))]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
```

If I remove the second method, the controller renders just fine in Swagger. However, if I include it, the routes are rendered like this:

```
GET /api/Foo
GET /api/Foo/{id}
```

What is going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by the attribute I was using. (Copy paste strikes again.)

These are **not** correct:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
[System.Web.Mvc.Route("api/v1.0/foo/{id}")]
```

Instead, these **are** correct:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/v1.0/foo/{id}")]
```